# Do apple app policies allow you to share the users IP address with 3rd parties

Tags: iphone, mobile, ads

I'm working on an iphone app and will be using a 3rd party advertising services.  The advertisting service want me to provide them with the users IP address via an API call.  This is so the ad service can track users across web and app.

So is the IP address counted as device information?  Do apple policies allow me to share the IP address with a 3rd party?  My privacy policy will indicate that I'm collecting and passing on the IP address.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple policies, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time your application makes a HTTP request, the receiving web server will get the calling device's IP address.  That's the nature of the beast.

Thousands of iOS applications make external HTTP requests and don't provide a custom EULA (look at all the apps out there with ads in them).

So, it is obviously not against Apple's policies.  IP addresses are not technically personally identifiable information.

However, you should not share the device's unique identifier (found by doing `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`) because that is considered personally identifiable information and could be use to track a specific user.  It may not be against Apple's policy, but it is likely illegal in the USA unless you provide a sufficient EULA.

Comment: Thanks.  Agreed, this is the nature of the beast.  Just seems subtly different to take this information and pass it on to a third party for the explicit purpose of tracking a user.  As you suggest though, this is entirely common place on the web and apps as well.  Just keen to be squeaky clean.